# MongoDB ObjectId(string) generates a new Id instead of the given string representing the id

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

after using Mongoose for a while, I've noticed that everytime when using `ObjectId(string of id from client)` or `new ObjectId(string of id from client)`, I would get a new Id, not the same as the input string Id. I thought this was the intended behaviour until recently. It seems that something in my setup is messed up. I am using Typegoose, Mongoose and Mongodb with Node and Typescript

```
npm ls mongoose
backend
├─┬ @typegoose/typegoose@8.3.0
│ └── mongoose@5.13.9 deduped
└─┬ mongoose@5.13.9
  └─┬ mongoose-legacy-pluralize@1.0.2
    └── mongoose@5.13.9 deduped

npm ls mongodb
backend
├── mongodb@3.6.11
└─┬ mongoose@5.13.9
  └── mongodb@3.6.11 deduped
```

These are my dependencies

```
 "dependencies": {
        "@typegoose/typegoose": "8.3.0",
        "@types/mongodb": "3.6.11",
        "mongodb": "3.6.11",
        "mongoose": "~5.13.8",
        "mongoose-to-swagger": "^1.3.0",
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "ts-node": "9.1.1",
        "tsc-alias": "^1.3.9",
        "tsconfig-paths": "^3.11.0",
        "typescript": "4.1.3"
    }
}
```

And this is the result

```
Input: channelId":"614728ed7f88e836fcc22827","senderId":"61471fdb6cb0b1129b8b7316","contents":""

Output:
{
_id: 6147361e69906069b52ab3d2,
senderId: 6147361e69906069b52ab3d0,
channelId: 6147361e69906069b52ab3d1,
}
```

Getting these values as such, but I've tried other methods of using ObjectId from Mongodb directly, from other dependencies and so on

```
    const model = await MessageModel.create({
        senderId:  new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(message.senderId),
        channelId:  new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(message.channelId),
        contents: message.contents,
      });
```

I've had this happen in every project of mine, any input on how to resolve it? [Full list of deps](https://hastebin.com/timizugiqo.pl)

Comment: Are you sure those fields are actually in “message”?  The behavior you describe is what would happen if the value passed to the ObjectId constructor is undefined

Comment: I printed them multiple times just before using the values. From what I've read if versions are jumbled and not aligned, similar unexpected behaviour can happen. But this isn't isolated to this case, had this happen in every project of mine.

Comment: The `Output` that you show, that doesn't contain quotes, is how Mongoose displays  objectID values.  Are the input values actually objectID already?

Comment: @Joe They are objectIds from another collection being sent by a client meaning they are strings.